# meaning of convergence at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

What does the following mean?

> A sequence of functions $f_n(z)$ converges to function $f(z)$ uniformly in the neighborhood of $\infty$.

This is from a complex analysis class.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you are working on the Riemann sphere, where $\infty$ is a point just like any other?

Comment: A neighborhood of an ordinary complex number $z$, as you know, is an arbitrarily small open disk.  A neighborhood of $\infty$ is the complement of an arbitrarily large closed disk.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result that has been used in real analysis. I think it should extend to complex too.

> $f_n$ converges uniformly on some nonempty set $A$, then it must satisfy the uniform Cauchy criterion, i.e. $||f_n - f_m||_{L^\infty(A)} \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$

I often find this useful when I am looking at functions converging uniformly to infinity. 
A simple illustration of the use of the result: $f_n = n$ does not converge uniformly to $f = \infty$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With this definition no function can converge to $\infty$... On the sphere you use the chordal metric, instead of the Euclidean, and then $n$ converges to $\infty$ in the chordal metric.